# Using an aggregate function with a lookup

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3 and I'm having trouble with a line chart not displaying the right figures when all my multi value parameter options are selected.

I was initially having problems with the x-axis not showing all the months when there was no data for them, so I've created a 'months' dataset and using that as my category group on the chart and using a 'Lookup' in my series value. This runs fine if I select just single values in my parameters but when I 'select all' things go wrong.

[image]

Adding 'Sum' to the expression (below) is what I thought would resolve the issue but this doesn't work

```
=Lookup(Fields!yyyy_mm.value,Fields!yyyy_mm.value,Fields!sum(All_Attended.value),"All_Attended")
```

I've also looked at using 'lookupset' but this also doesn't work

```
=sum(Lookupset(Fields!yyyy_mm.value,Fields!yyyy_mm.value,Fields!sum(All_Attended.value),"All_Attended"))
```

The query for my dataset looks a little like this

```
select

 Fiscal,[yyyy_mm],localauthority,ward,
 sum(case when Field = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) as ABC,
 sum(case when Field = 'DEF' then 1 else 0 end) as DEF,
 sum(case when Field in ('ABC,'DEF') then 1 else 0 end) as All_Attended

 group by Fiscal,[yyyy_mm],localauthority,ward
```

And the data looks like this

```
 Fiscal      yyyy_mm      localauthority    ward   ABC  DEF   All_Attended  
 15/16       2015-07         east          hampton  5    5        10
 16/17       2016-01         north          dale    2    2        4
 16/17       2016-01         north          port    1    0        1
```

these are my parameters
[image]

This is the report when ran, as you can see I should be expecting much larger numbers in my chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have managed to find a site which had the answer. Not sure if I'm allowed to post links to other websites though. The solution requires some VBA code.

Comment: you can edit your question and write in information stating you found answer with xyz website and past url